# Cumulatively add month to a Date column based off the first date of a group

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I have a data frame where I'm trying to add a new column based on the condition that adds 3 months to a DateTime.

```
ID1    ID2          Date
 1     20    5/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
 1     21    5/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
 1     22    6/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
 2     30    7/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
 2     31    7/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
 2     32    7/15/2019  11:06:47 AM
```

**Required Output,**

```
ID1    ID2          Date                   NewDate
 1     20    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    8/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     21    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    9/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     22    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     30    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     31    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    11/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     32    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    12/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
```

For each ID1, there can be only one unique NewDate. If there exists a date that may fall in the same month, then add another month.

**For ID1, having a different Date, if the NewDate falls on a month similar to previous NewDate, then we add another additional DateOffset as seen in Row 3 of the required output**

I have tried the following code,

```
def add_date(df):
    for each_ID1 in df['ID1']:
        for each_ID2 in df['ID2']:
            return df['Date'] + DateOffset(months = 3)
    
df['New Date'] = df.apply(add_date, axis = 1)
```

My code gives me the 3-month DateOffset only as shown,

```
ID1    ID2          Date                   NewDate
 1     20    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    8/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     21    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    8/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     22    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    9/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     30    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     31    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 2     32    7/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
```

**Output Error**

```
ID1    ID2          Date                   NewDate
 1     20    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    8/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     21    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    9/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     22    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     23    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    11/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     24    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    12/15/2020 11:06:47 AM
 1     25    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    01/15/2021 11:06:47 AM
 1     26    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    10/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     27    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    12/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     28    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    02/15/2020 11:06:47 AM
 1     29    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    04/15/2020 11:06:47 AM
 1     30    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    06/15/2020 11:06:47 AM
 1     31    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM    07/15/2020 11:06:47 AM
```

Comment: For ID1 == 1 there seems to still be a collision with the 2nd and 3rd row (because of the duplication with the first two rows) so the second row + 4 months is the same as the third row + 3 months. Should that stay as is, or be handled differently?

Comment: @ALollz It should stay as it is because we take ID2 into consideration too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create a series `m` with a `.groupby` on the column `ID1`, return the cumulative count per group, and add 3 (since that is how many months you want to offset initially). With `.cumcount()`, the offset will grow by 1 with each additional row of your group.
2. Then, we want to create the `New Date` column but ONLY Add `m` to the FIRST date of each group, so we use `df.groupby('ID1')['Date'].transform('first')` before adding `m.values.astype("timedelta64[M]")`:

Input (Latest Edit of your question):

```
ID1    ID2          Date        
 1     20    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     21    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     22    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     23    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     24    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     25    5/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
 1     26    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     27    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     28    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     29    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM  
 1     30    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM 
 1     31    6/15/2019 11:06:47 AM
```

---

```
# df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
m = df.groupby('ID1').cumcount() + 3
df['New Date'] = df.groupby('ID1')['Date'].transform('first') + m.values.astype("timedelta64[M]")
df
Out[1]: 
    ID1  ID2                Date            New Date
0     1   20 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2019-08-14 18:34:05
1     1   21 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2019-09-14 05:03:11
2     1   22 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2019-10-14 15:32:17
3     1   23 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2019-11-14 02:01:23
4     1   24 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2019-12-14 12:30:29
5     1   25 2019-05-15 11:06:47 2020-01-13 22:59:35
6     1   26 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-02-13 09:28:41
7     1   27 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-03-14 19:57:47
8     1   28 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-04-14 06:26:53
9     1   29 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-05-14 16:55:59
10    1   30 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-06-14 03:25:05
11    1   31 2019-06-15 11:06:47 2020-07-14 13:54:11
```

Comment: The output works partially. Sorry I missed one information. I have updated the question and changed row 3 of the required output. The row 3 has a different Date for ID1 but it's NewDate cant overlap with a previous NewDate. Can you help make that change?

Comment: @AmoghKatwe check the revised solution. It uses the first solution as the bsae and then you need to identify duplicates by `ID1` and the year/month of the `New Date` column from the first solution, and count the number of dupes per group cumulatively, so that you can add the number of months in a vectorized manner. Taking the `.cumsum()` of b`boolea` `True` or `False` values is essentially counting dupes per group cumulatively.

Comment: The code made errors when the month changed for the Date. I have edited the question by adding an output error. You will see that until row 6, the NewDate worked fine. But when the Date changed to June, New Date goes back to October which is already present in the previous NewDate column. It was supposed to give New Date as  Feb 2020 and so on. I hope this helps.

Comment: @AmoghKatwe Okay, so I think it is actually super straightforward. We actually just need to take the first value of each group and simply add one month to it for each row until we get to the next group. Please confrim it works and I'm going to delete the first two parts of my answer as the solution is quite easy after looking at the larger dataset.

Comment: Oh boy. Yes, it did work. It was quite simple. My bad for not posting a larger dataset. It's great learning about leveraging this platform. Thanks to you, I learned some more stuff about pandas.